# mysql: Create a Table to another schema from a function

Tags: mysql, function

I would like a function that creates, if not exist, a table to another schema and then it inserts a values into a table. I tried to create the following function

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `testFun`(oldStr VARCHAR(256), newStr VARCHAR(256)) RETURNS boolean
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS association.Association(email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, maskedEmail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

    INSERT INTO association.Association (email, maskedEmail) VALUES (oldStr, newStr );

    RETURN TRUE;

END
```

but when I try to execute the function, mysqlWorkBench returns the following error:

```
ERROR 1422: Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.
```

Comment: That will be the create table. Why do you want to this from a function?

Comment: Because, it useful for me to create dynamically a table that it contain an association between email and masked e-mail

Comment: MYsql is not going to allow you to create a table so you are going to have to tackle this another way perhaps in a trigger.

Comment: @P.Salmon triggers don't allow implicit commits, either.

Comment: @giupardeb it feels like you are solving the wrong problem.  It this table will be needed, then just create it now.  If other parts of your code are checking it, then it needs to be there, anyway, even if it is empty.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I would create as much as generally function. If I want to masking an email, the function will create a table Email_association. If I want to masking a First name, the function will create a table First_name association, and so on.. I don't want to create a statically Table.